# Is there a clean way to *skip* an array index using PHP's `list()`?

Tags: php

Say I have a function that returns an array like this...

```
array(
    0 => 'jpg',
    1 => 400,
    2 => 500
);
```

I want the indexes 1 and 2 only, and I want them as local variables. I don't care about 0.

I could do...

```
list($throwaway, $width, $height) = getImageDetails($imagePath);
unset($throwaway);
```

...but obviously that is very ugly.

I tried placing `NULL` there, but I got the scope resolution error.

Is there a clean way to *skip* an array index using PHP's `list()`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yep, don't populate that argument, this is perfectly valid:

```
list(, $width, $height) = getImageDetails($imagePath);
```

(see also [Example 1 in the manual](https://www.php.net/list))

Comment: @#$%! I remember doing this in the past! Thanks for your answer and jogging my memory!

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of another one-liner:

```
list($width, $height) = array_slice(getImageDetails($imagePath), 1, 2);
```

[Demo.](http://www.ideone.com/6CXCV)

Then there's the slightly more entertaining:

```
list($height, $width) = array_reverse(getImageDetails($imagePath));
```

[Demo.](http://www.ideone.com/GKVhz)